# React Question: Undefined Values passing data into props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling to find a solution to this problem. I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'Department_ID' of undefined errors from props being passed in from parent state. The main problem I'm seeing is that the Departments data is not being passed to the child element. Please look at the code and tell me what I'm missing! Thank you in advance for whatever help you can give me!

Parent Component: Positions

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import API_access from '../../API_access'
import Position from './Position';

function Positions() {
    const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);
    const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);
    const [_position_ID, setPositionID] = useState('');
    const [_title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [_department_ID, setDepartmentID] = useState();
    const [_department_name, setDepartmentName] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const get_data = async() => {
            const jobs = await API_access('/API/Positions', 'GET');
            const depts = await API_access('/API/Departments', 'GET');
            setPositions(jobs.data);
            setDepartments(depts.data); 
        }
        get_data();
    },[])

    const Create_Position = async () => {
        let new_position = {
            Position_ID: _position_ID,
            Position_Title: _title,
            Department_ID: _department_ID
        }
        const success = await API_access('/API/Positions', 'POST', new_position);
        if (success) {
            let tmpArray = positions;
            tmpArray.push(new_position);
            setPositions(tmpArray);
        }
    }

    const Update_Position = async (position) => {
        const success = await API_access('/API/Positions', 'PATCH', position);
        if (success) {
            let tmpArray = positions.filter(pos => pos.Position_ID !== position.Position_ID);
            tmpArray.push(position);
            setPositions(tmpArray);
        }
    }

    const Delete_Position = async (position) => {
        const success = await API_access('/API/Positions', position);
        if(success) {
            let tmpArray = positions.filter(pos => pos.Position_ID !== position.Position_ID);
            setPositions(tmpArray);
        }
    }

    const Set_Department_Data = (event) => {
        setDepartmentName(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
        setDepartmentID(event.target.value);
    }
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="txtPositionID" value={_position_ID} onChange={event => setPositionID(event.target.value)}/>
                    <label htmlFor="txtPositionID">Position ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtTitle" value={_title} onChange={event => setTitle(event.target.value)}/>
                    <label htmlFor="txtTitle">Job Title</label>
                    <select value={_department_ID} text={_department_name} onChange={event => Set_Department_Data(event)}>
                        <option value="" disabled>Select Department</option>
                        {departments.map((department, index) => (
                            <option key={index} value={department.Department_ID}>{department.Department_Name}</option>
                            ))}
                    </select>
                    <button onClick={() => Create_Position}>Save</button>
                </form>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Edit</td>
                            <td>Position ID</td>
                            <td>Job Title</td>
                            <td>Department</td>
                            <td>Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {positions.length > 0 && positions.map((position, index) => (
                            <Position key={index} Position={position} Departments={departments} Update_Position={Update_Position} Delete_Position={Delete_Position}/>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
}
export default Positions
```

Child Element: Position

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function Position({ Position, Departments, Update_Position, Delete_Position  }) {
    const [_department_ID, setDepartmentID] = useState(Position.Department_ID);
    const [_department_name, setDepartmentName] = useState('');
    const [_job_title, setJobTitle] = useState(Position.Position_Title);
    const [_edit, toggleEdit] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const set_data = () => {
            console.log(Departments)
            console.log(_department_ID)
            let dept = Departments.find(d => String(d.Department_ID) === String(_department_ID));
            console.log(dept)
            setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
            setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name)
        }
        set_data();
    }, [])

    const Set_Department_Data = (event) => {
        setDepartmentName(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
        setDepartmentID(event.target.value);
    }

    const Update_This_Position = () => {
        if (_edit) {
            let pos = {
                Position_ID: Position.Position_ID,
                Position_Title: _job_title,
                Department_ID: _department_ID
            }
            Update_Position(pos);
        } 
        toggleEdit(!_edit);
    }

    if (_edit) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td><button onClick={() => Update_This_Position()}>Save</button></td>
                <td>{Position.Position_ID}</td>
                <td><input type="text" value={_job_title} onChange={event => setJobTitle(event.target.value)}/> </td>
                <td><select value={_department_ID} text={_department_name} onChange={event => Set_Department_Data(event)}>
                    {Departments.map((department, index) => (
                        <option key={index} value={department.Department_ID}>{department.Department_Name}</option>
                    ))}
                    </select></td>
                <td><button onClick={() => Delete_Position(Position)}>X</button></td>
            </tr>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td><button onClick={() => Update_This_Position()}>&gt;</button></td>
                <td>{Position.Position_ID}</td>
                <td>{Position.Position_Title}</td>
                <td>{_department_name}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => Delete_Position(Position)}>X</button></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

export default Position
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Department_ID' of undefined
set_data
src/components/Personnel/Position.js:15
  12 |     console.log(_department_ID)
  13 |     let dept = Departments.find(d => String(d.Department_ID) === String(_department_ID));
  14 |     console.log(dept)
> 15 |     setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
     | ^  16 |     setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name)
  17 | }
  18 | set_data();
View compiled
(anonymous function)
src/components/Personnel/Position.js:18
  15 |         setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
  16 |         setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name)
  17 |     }
> 18 |     set_data();
     | ^  19 | }, [])
  20 | 
  21 | const Set_Department_Data = (event) => {
View compiled
▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
get_data
src/components/Personnel/Positions.js:18
  15 |         const jobs = await API_access('/API/Positions', 'GET');
  16 |         const depts = await API_access('/API/Departments', 'GET');
  17 |         setPositions(jobs.data);
> 18 |         setDepartments(depts.data); 
     | ^  19 |     }
  20 |     get_data();
  21 | },[])
View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can return `undefined` if no element passes the predicate condition.

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

During the initial render cycle `departments` is an empty array, so `dept` is all but guaranteed to be `undefined` on the initial render.

```
const set_data = () => {
  console.log(Departments)
  console.log(_department_ID)
  let dept = Departments.find(d => String(d.Department_ID) === String(_department_ID));
  console.log(dept)
  setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
  setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name)
}
```

## Solution

You should check for valid results from the `find` before accessing the result.

```
const set_data = () => {
  const deptId = String(_department_ID);
  const dept = Departments.find(d => String(d.Department_ID) === deptId);
  if (dept) {
    setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
    setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name);
  }
}
```

BUT, this code is running in an `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency, so the hook runs only once when the component mounts. You've a couple options:

1. Add a dependency to the `useEffect` hook to set the component state when the `Departments` prop updates.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const set_data = () => {
       const deptId = String(_department_ID);
       const dept = Departments.find(d => String(d.Department_ID) === deptId);
       if (dept) {
         setDepartmentID(dept.Department_ID);
         setDepartmentName(dept.Department_Name);
       }
     }
     set_data();
   }, [Departments]); // <-- dependency
   ```
2. Conditionally render `Position` only when ***all*** of the props are populated. Ensure both `positions` *and* `departments` arrays have a truthy (non-zero) length.

   ```
   <tbody>
     {positions.length && departments.length && positions.map((position, index) => (
       <Position
         key={index}
         Position={position}
         Departments={departments}
         Update_Position={Update_Position}
         Delete_Position={Delete_Position}
       />
     ))}
   </tbody>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t think child components were rendered until parent components were so it didn’t occur to me the arrays failed to populate before rendering the child elements. Putting the check in the render function fixed it!